# Start Reading from a specific point to EOF using BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a class that reads through a log file line by line and I would like to begin from a specific point in the file until the end of the file. For example, start reading from timestamp '2018-11-23 09:00' to the end of the file. I have checked BufferedReader questions relating to reading a file but none of answers helped.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(!line.isEmpty()){//I would like to start reading from a specific timestamp to the end of the file
        if(line.toLowerCase().contains(keyword)){
            if(line.length() > 16) {
                if (line.substring(0, 1).matches("\\d")){
                    dateTimeSet.add(line.substring(0, 16));//Adds timestamp to my list
                    errorSet.add(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some sample lines of your data so we can see the format. Basically you're going to be reading and discarding lines until you hit your trigger then you will process lines from that point onwards.

Comment: It's a log file, some lines begin with a time stamp, e.g. 2018-11-16 08:11:00,569.

Comment: @OAM I have exactly the same question as you, but your code DOES NOT JUMP TO A SPECIFIC LINE, it still goes thru the whole file and checking conditions of the line...so even your own code example does not correspond to the title, unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a special string to occur in your file you need to check each line until you find it.

Add a local variable to keep track of if you should process the line or skip it

```
boolean isReading = false;
```

Then instead of your `isEmpty`check do

```
 if (!isReading) {
     isReading = line.startsWith(timestamp);
 }

 if (!isReading) {
     continue;
 }

 //otherwise process line
```

If you can't always match the timestamp you might be better of using `matches()` and a regular expression instead of `startsWith()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, where on my code will those two if statements fit?